# Pygame screen display issue

Tags: python, pygame, display

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


display_width = (640)
display_height = (480)

title = pygame.display.set_caption("test")
IMG = pygame.image.load("image.png")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

screen.blit(IMG,(1,1))

pygame.display.update()
```

Whenever I use pygame, even simple displays like this are skewed for me. it shows 0,0 at around the middle of my display screen and i dont know why. Basically, it is showing - x values on the x axis help!
I am using python 2.7 and this seems to not be a coding issue, but rather something else. please help! ty

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to replicate your problem with the above code in Python 2.7.12, the image is a red, fifty-pixel square:

[image: Demo code]

Here's an extended demo that will draw the image around the cursor position based on the mouse button clicked. Perhaps that'll help you get towards the behaviour you're after.

```
import pygame

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    screen_width, screen_height = 640, 480
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Blit Demo')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock() #for limiting FPS
    FPS = 10
    exit_demo = False
    # start with a white background
    screen.fill(pygame.Color("white"))
    img = pygame.image.load("image.png")
    width, height = img.get_size()
    pos = (1,1)  # initial position to draw the image
    # main loop
    while not exit_demo:
        for event in pygame.event.get():            
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit_demo = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    # fill the screen with white, erasing everything
                    screen.fill(pygame.Color("white"))
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if event.button == 1:  # left
                    pos = (event.pos[0] - width, event.pos[1] - height)                   
                elif event.button == 2: # middle
                    pos = (event.pos[0] - width // 2, event.pos[1] - height // 2)
                elif event.button == 3: # right
                    pos = event.pos

        # draw the image here
        screen.blit(img, pos)
        # update screen
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```